# Can $(-1)^{a+i b}$ be expressed without negative based exponentiation, complex exponentiation, complex logarithms or trigonometric functions?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Can this expression, where $a$ and $b$ are both real, be expressed without negative based exponentiation (i.e. $a^b$ where $a$ is negative), complex exponentiation, complex logarithms or trigonometric functions?

$$(-1)^{a+i b}$$

I've got it to this, but can't work out how to refactor the negative based exponentiation.

$$e^{-b\pi}(-1)^a$$

Comment: First, this is an expression, not an equation. But more importantly, what do you want take as _definition_ of exponentiation? Ordinarily $x^y$ with $y$ non-integer is only defined if $x$ is real and positive, and it then means $\exp(\ln(x)y)$. But something like $(-1)^{2/3}$ is not well defined, and if you obstinately insist on giving it a meaning it would be via the complex exponentiation and logarithm (but the result could equally well be $-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2\mathbf i$ as $-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2\mathbf i$ which is why it _should_ be left undefined).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Perhaps another form is the best way I can define $(-1)^a$ where $a$ is real — $\cos(\pi a)+i\sin(\pi a)$.

Comment: You want that we give sense to an expression without obvious sense, but are explicitly forbidding all means that we could use to give it some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I've come to an answer works when $a$ is a positive multiple of $1\over4$
$$
e^{-b\pi}(\sqrt {0.5} + i \sqrt {0.5})^{4a}
$$
and since simple multiplication can be used like so
$$
(a + bi)(c + di) = (ac – bd) + (ad + bc)i.
$$
$$
(a+bi)^2 = (a^2-b^2)+(2ab)i
$$
this doesn't require complex exponentiation.

For $a$ not a multiple of $1\over4$, other values can be used. For example, slightly more unwieldy is this, which works with values of $a$ multiples of $1\over60$.
$$
e^{-b\pi}\left(\frac{1}{16} \left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{20+4 \sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{60+12 \sqrt{5}}\right) + i \frac{1}{16} \left(-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{20+4 \sqrt{5}}-\sqrt{60+12 \sqrt{5}}\right)\right)^{60a}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you write $\exp(-b\pi)$ $[ln(e^{-1})]^a$, that should satisfy all your criteria (if I understand complex exponentiation in a way similar to what you defined as being negative exponentiation). There are plenty of choices for what to put between $[~]$, as long it is a function that gives $-1$ and meets your criteria.

Comment: This is as much a non-answer to the question as $\exp(-b\pi)(1-2)^a$ is, that is it still uses a non-integral power of a negative number (and in fact it still uses $(-1)^a$).

Answer (score -1):

Interesting.
$$
\mathrm{Re}\big((-1)^{ib}\big) = \cos(b\pi)
$$
to be expressed without trig functions...  And without any of the known ways to epxress trig functions.

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: It is an assertion that there is no known answer.